# Can an object in R have more than one class?

Tags: r, oop

Suppose I have a function like this:

```
myf = function(x) {
res = dostuff(x)
res # this is a data.frame
}
```

I want to do something special about `res`, for example, 
I want to make some generic functions like `print.myf, summary.myf, ...`
, so I can go ahead and give it a class:

```
myf = function(x) {
res = dostuff(x)
class(res) = 'myf'
res
}
```

But this way I cannot use it as a data.frame any more.

Comment: Yes. In your function, rewrite `class(res) = "myf"` to `class(res) <- c("myf", class(res))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example with `rle`. The `rle` function creates a `list`, but it doesn't have the class `list`, so methods like `as.data.frame` won't work "out of the box". As such, I've changed the last line to add `"list"` as one of the classes.

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)

rle2 <- function (x)
{
  if (!is.vector(x) && !is.list(x))
    stop("'x' must be an atomic vector")
  n <- length(x)
  if (n == 0L)
    return(structure(list(lengths = integer(), values = x),
                     class = "rle"))
  y <- x[-1L] != x[-n]
  i <- c(which(y | is.na(y)), n)

  ## THE FOLLOWING IS FROM THE BASE RLE. NOTICE ONLY ONE CLASS...
  # structure(list(lengths = diff(c(0L, i)), values = x[i]), 
  #  class = "rle")

  structure(list(lengths = diff(c(0L, i)), values = x[i]),
            class = c("rle", "list"))
}
```

As you can see, I've simply changed the `class`. The rest of the function is the same.

```
rle(x)
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:3] 4 3 7
#   values : num [1:3] 1 2 3
data.frame(rle(x))
# Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
#   cannot coerce class ""rle"" to a data.frame
rle2(x)
# Run Length Encoding
#   lengths: int [1:3] 4 3 7
#   values : num [1:3] 1 2 3
data.frame(rle2(x))
#   lengths values
# 1       4      1
# 2       3      2
# 3       7      3
```

---

Of course, if we know this, we could also explicitly specify our methods if we know one exists:

```
as.data.frame.list(rle(x))
#   lengths values
# 1       4      1
# 2       3      2
# 3       7      3
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, my standard (simple) example is

```
R> now <- Sys.time()
R> class(now)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
R> class(as.POSIXlt(now))
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" 
R>
```

It is also the reason behind the pro tip of testing with `inherits("someClass")` rather than testing the result of `class(obj)=="someClass"`.